# "An internal error occurred" when trying to commit to git from eGit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, github, egit

[SOLVED] Somehow, I managed to not have "write" permissions to the .git directory. So was trying to write the commit and getting bounced.

I've been using Eclipse for a few months, but had been just running git from the CLI. I decided that was inefficient and that I wanted to use eGit, so I started following this tutorial (http://www.slideshare.net/loianeg/using-the-egit-eclipse-plugin-with-git-hub-2578587?from=embed).

I'm trying to add an existing project, so I did Team-->Share Project-->Git and selected the .git corresponding to my project. Eclipse seems to have picked it up, okay, but when I try to commit, I get a popup saying

"Committing changes has encountered a problem' -- an internal error occured.

When I click details, it say "An internal error occurred
Exception caught during execution of commit command"

...I don't even know where to start on this one. I googled the error and didn't get anything useful.

Anyone know how to fix this, or at least how to start debugging?

Comment: Excellent. I have edited my answer below to make your conclusion more visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- start debugging?
  Check the "Errors" Eclipse view for a full Stack Trace associate with that error message

Example of an Error View:

[image: Show Error View]
[image: Eclipse Error View]

- fix it?
  If the Exception is a NPE one (NullPointerException), like shown in [bug 329611](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329611), then you can try a git commit -m "a message" in a shell, in order to get past that initial first commit with a GUI.

---

As the [OP rogueleaderr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998687/rogueleaderr) mentions, the error view and the exact stack trace behind the exception was enough:

> **Somehow, I managed to not have "write" permissions to the `.git` directory.**
>   So was trying to write the commit and getting bounced.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the errors view...that would have helped me track this down.

Answer (score 8):

I've solved my case removing index.lock file from the git folder of the project.

Answer (score 3):

I face this problem too, Error tab doesn't show anything more. 
So I use GitExtension to commit instead, problem solved.

Using parallel eGit and GitExtension to keep tracking a local git repo is a good idea. It's update runtime on both Eclipse and GitExtension when we make change on each.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem. I delete the `.git` folder and `.gitignore` file push to upstream it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  I resolved it by committing manually from terminal using (in this order):

`git add .` then `git commit` and lastly, `git push` from the local repo directory.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, It was resolved after deleting index.lock file in .git\ folder.